# Find / search the AOT for an exact match

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

Is it possible to find (search) in Dynamics AX 2009 for an exact match?

For example, when I am searching in the AOT for "AddressRelationship", I don't want to see DirPartyAddressRelationship in the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it took me a while, but I have figured this out, it **Is possible**.

Adding a breakpoint to the find form shows that it uses a class called `SysUtilScanSource` to find your string within the AX source code.

In `SysUtilScanSource.do()` the method `match` is used to find a match against the specific source code. You can read more about `match` here;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa886279(v=ax.10).aspx

The `match` method allows you to use expressions.

The expression you require is as follows;

**:SPACE**

> Where SPACE is the character ' '. Sets the match to blanks, tabulations, and control characters such as Enter (new line).

**For example:**

```
match("ab: cd","ab cd"); //returns 1 
match("ab: cd","ab\ncd"); //returns 1 
match("ab: cd","ab\tcd"); //returns 1
match("ab: cd","ab cd"); //returns 0 - only the first space is matched
```

**Therefore, in your example you need enter the following string in the "containing text" field;**

```
: AddressRelationship:
```

Note that in the above string there are spaces in the following locations;

```
:SPACEAddressRelationship:SPACE
```

*Try it. I did, it works a treat.*

Answer (score 0):

When you do the find, look at "properties" tab at the end of the find form window. This allows you to scale down the search based on properties. I do not believe there is a way to use an exact match but you can narrow your search down using the properties.