# Find / search case sensitive

Tags: axapta

Is it possible to do a case sensitive find (search) in Dynamics AX 2009?

For example, when I am searching for "address", I don't want to see "Address" in the results.

Comment: Searching where? Editor? Find? Ranges?

Comment: you have asked this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056800/dynamics-ax-2009-find-search-for-an-exact-match

Comment: I have answered on your original question, here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056800/dynamics-ax-2009-find-search-for-an-exact-match

Comment: Well strictly speaking it is two different aspects: case sensitive versus exact search. Maybe we are best to leave it as is. Both questions are vague on there scope.

Comment: I didn't spot that! Added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jan,

There IS a way to do it using standard Axapta X++.  When you use the find screen there is a tab called 'Filter' where you can place code to do the filtering (no need to complete the fields on the name & location tab).  The below code is for illustration purposes only as the below code is not complete and has not been finalised (I leave that to you).

```
str             toMatch     = 'Address';
str             string;
str             char, charMatch;
int             i, pos;
boolean         ret;
;

pos     = strScan(_treeNodeName, toMatch, 1, strLen(_treeNodeName));
string  = subStr(_treeNodeName, pos, strLen(toMatch));
if (string)
{
    ret             = true;
    for (i=1;i<=strLen(toMatch);i++)
    {
        char        = subStr(toMatch, i, 1);
        charMatch   = subStr(string, i, 1);
        if (char2num(char,1) != char2num(charMatch,1))
        {
            ret     = false;
        }
    }
    if (ret)
    {
        return ret;
    }
}

pos     = strScan(_treeNodeSource, toMatch, 1, strLen(_treeNodeSource));
string  = subStr(_treeNodeSource, pos, strLen(toMatch));
if (string)
{
    ret             = true;
    for (i=1;i<=strLen(toMatch);i++)
    {
        char        = subStr(toMatch, i, 1);
        charMatch   = subStr(string, i, 1);
        if (char2num(char,1) != char2num(charMatch,1))
        {
            ret     = false;
        }
    }
    if (ret)
    {
        return ret;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it sounds plausible. Thanks for the code to get me started. I wonder what kind of of effect on performance the filter will have?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the Find form window that appears when you do a find,  look at the properties, this helps you narrow you down your search, unsure about a like-for-like exact match i.e. "address" and blocking out "Address".

Answer (score 0):

**No you cannot.**

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056800/find-search-the-aot-for-an-exact-match), the find form uses the `match` method, which is documented [on msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa886279%28v=ax.10%29.aspx).

To quote MSDN;

> Remarks
>
> The system does not differentiate between lower and upper case.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, but it is what it is. Thank you.